# Text cell reference in setting workbook path

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script that opens a different workbook located on my desktop. There are two variables in the path that determines the location of file I wish to open: (1) the user of the PC; (2) the name of the file. 
The user of the PC variable is defined on cell J3, but the the name of the file on J2, both on the same sheet. The code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Chakars()

    Dim BeiguSheet As Worksheet
    Dim FileJauda As String

    Set BeiguSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Final")

        FileJauda = "C:\Users\ugikam\Desktop\" & "Jauda_" & BeiguSheet.Range("J2").Value & ".xlsm"

    Workbooks.Open (FileJauda)

End Sub
```

In the line where FileJauda is defined, you can see the reference to cell J2 which works properly. However, when I try to replace another variable in path (namely, user which is "ugikam") by using the line below it could not locate the file anymore. Where is the issue? Could it be related to the fact that "ugikam" is a string of text?

FileJauda = "C:\" & BeiguSheet.Range("J3").Value & "\Desktop\" & "Jauda_" & BeiguSheet.Range("J2").Value & ".xlsm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may occurred from invisible characters. i try to clean both strings with the below code. Additionally, you could debug and check one by one cell value using intimidate window. Lastly, you try to open workbook with name **FilePath** which is not defined anywhere. try replacing *Workbooks.Open (FilePath)* with *Workbooks.Open (FileJauda)*

```
Option Explicit

Sub Chakars()

    Dim BeiguSheet As Worksheet
    Dim FileJauda As String

    Set BeiguSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Final")

        With BeiguSheet
            FileJauda = "C:\" & _
                        Application.Clean(Application.Trim(.Range("J3").Value)) & _
                        "\Desktop\Jauda_" & _
                        Application.Clean(Application.Trim(.Range("J2").Value)) & _
                        ".xlsm"
        End With

    Workbooks.Open (FileJauda)

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the question code - FilePath was the last definition, I had changed it to FileJauda. Anyway, I just tried your script it returns the same exact error. The error message says "Sorry, we couldn't find C:\ugikam\Desktop\Jauda_20190415.xlsm". I am 100% sure this is the right path for that file, I had the same result for my code as well, but for some reason it doesn't work although the user has been properly placed in the path.

Comment: Copy the path (C:\ugikam\Desktop\Jauda_20190415.xlsm), Open a File Explorer (Windows Key + E) & paste. Check what result you get. The file should open.

Comment: I restarted excel and the your code just worked. I don't know what was wrong, but thanks, that really helped!